# Create Materialized View using SELECT and adding new values where NULL

Tags: sql, oracle

I am attempting to create a materialized view in SQL Developer using a SELECT statement referencing an existing table but would like to add values to the materialized view if a column value in the existing table is null, otherwise just leave the column value as per the table.

For example:

```
Create materialized view MVIEW_NAME as (
 SELECT A.* from tableOne A
   CASE WHEN A.colName IS NULL THEN A.colName=NewValue
   END CASE
)
```

Clearly the syntax for this is incorrect but not sure how to do it or if there is an IF STATEMENT or something that could do it? Thanks for any help.

Comment: Why do you want a materialized view instead of a regular view?

Comment: Unrelated, but: the parentheses around the select are totally useless

Comment: Hi Jelly welcome to SO. Your question doesn't show much research. There is plenty of documentation available on how to create materialized view. Kindly read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask before asking your next question.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name while not syntactically necessary, I often use them in this case as I find it adds clarity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a function called NVL().
It checks whether a String is null and if so, it will replace it:

```
SELECT A.col1, A.col2, NVL(TO_CHAR(A.col3), 'Your new value') from tableOne A
```

It is not clear if the new value should be another column or not. If you just want to replace a NULL column with a value then this would be the easies way.
You can also use CASE WHEN directly in the select statement and use another column instead. Like this:

```
SELECT A.Col1,
CASE A.Col2 WHEN NULL THEN A.Col3
WHEN 0 THEN A.Col3
ELSE A.Col2 END
FROM tableOne A
```

Comment: Thanks Mono. I wanted to simply replace the NULL so NVL looks like the best way to go. However, there is one more complexity, I would like the new value to be based on an existing column value (dateofbirth) in a different table which joins on an different (firstname) column.  For example NVL (TO_CHAR(A.col3, SELECT firstname from TABLE2 b where a.name=b.firstname b.dateofbirth), is this possible? Thanks again!

Comment: You can just use  NVL(A.col1, B.col2) as colName. The TO_CHAR is only necessary for non Text columns.

Answer (score 0):

You need to put the case expression in the select list,

```
select 
      case when a.colname is null 
         then newvalue
         else a.colname
      end as colname,
      [other columns]
   from tableone
```

However, you could do it more simply with [`coalesce`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/functions023.htm):

```
select 
      coalesce(a.colname,newvalue) as colname,
      [other columns]
   from tableone
```

Note that this means you can't use `a.*` any more, unless you want one of the columns to be duplicated in the result.

Comment: Case expression, not case statement.